# How would I do a yes/no type SQL query?

Tags: sql

I just wanted to see a list of employees and a YES or NO next to their name if they are a supervisor. This is ANSI SQL not an implementation (I think thats what you call it). I was testing the commands at:
http://edu.konagora.com/SQLsandbox.php#

Here's what I came up with:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, CAST
(
   CASE
   WHEN Empl_ID IN (SELECT Empl_ID FROM Supervisor)
   THEN "YES"
   ELSE "NO"
   END AS varchar(3)
) AS 'ISS'
FROM Employee;
```

I get: (On Konagora.edu)

```
SQL Error: no such table: array
```

tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Supervisor
(
    Super_ID mediumint not null auto_increment,
    Empl_ID mediumint not null
);
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
    Empl_ID mediumint not null auto_increment,
    firstname varchar(100) not null,
    lastname varchar(100) not null,
    salary mediumint not null
);
```

Comment: And what is the problem with your query?

Comment: You're using `""` where you need `''`, and vice versa. And your `SELECT Empl_ID FROM Supervisor` is presumably supposed to be `SELECT Super_ID FROM Supervisor`.

Comment: I guess the error would be it can't figure out how to use the subquery in the if statement.

Comment: @Ruakh I tried switching the single and double quotes. Same Error.

Comment: Also, curiously, I tried `WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Supervisor WHERE Supervisor.Empl_ID=Empl_ID)>0`. Same error. I don't what to do here. Is there a way to do this w/o a subquery? (And modifying the tables)

Comment: Given that your error-message complains about `array`, when that does not appear in your query, I think you can now dispense with your naive hope that you were dealing with "ANSI SQL not an implementation".

Comment: Make the best out of a bad situation? the jury is in: no subqueries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

aside from the other comment notes about single vs double quotes, you would be better doing a LEFT JOIN to the supervisor table .

```
SELECT 
      E.firstname, 
      E.lastname, 
      case when S.Empl_ID IS NULL then 'NO' else 'YES' end as Iss
   from
      Employee E
         LEFT JOIN Supervisor S
            on E.Empl_ID = S.Empl_ID
```